# define a function name instead of lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing online tutorial and found python program, which returns a list with 2-tuples. Each tuple consists of a the order number and the product of the price pere items and the quantity. The product should be increased by 10,if the value of the order is less than 100.00

For my own understanding I want replicate by re-define the program with a function name.

```
orders = [ ["34587","Learning Python, Mark Lutz", 4, 40.95], 
           ["98762","Programming Python, Mark Lutz", 5, 56.80], 
               ["77226","Head First Python, Paul Barry",3,32.95]]

min_order = 100
invoice_totals = list(map(lambda x: x if x[1] >= min_order else (x[0], x[1] + 10) , 
              map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2] * x[3]), orders)))

print(invoice_totals)
```

This is what I have got so far.

```
def get_order(L):
    invoice_totals= []
    for item in range(len(L)):
        ordernum = L[item][0],
        if (L[item][2] * L[item][3])>= min_order:
            invoice_totals=  ordernum, (L[item][2] * L[item][3])
        else:
            invoice_totals=   ordernum, (L[item][2] * L[item][3]) + 10
        print( invoice_totals        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_order(orders)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you were to replicate the lambda solution above by defining function name how you would approach the alternative

Answer (score 0):

I would start by "naming" the anonymous functions:

```
min_order = 100

l1 = lambda x: x if x[1] >= min_order else (x[0], x[1] + 10)
l2 = lambda x: (x[0], x[2] * x[3])

invoice_totals = list(map(l1, map(l2, orders)))
```

`map(l1, map(l2, orders))` is basically `map(l1 of l2, orders)`, where `l1 of l2` is function composition. Your final function is just the composition of the two:

```
min_order = 100

l1 = lambda x: x if x[1] >= min_order else (x[0], x[1] + 10)
l2 = lambda x: (x[0], x[2] * x[3])
l3 = lambda x: l1(l2(x))

invoice_totals = list(map(l3, orders))
```

Or:

```
def l1(x):
    if x[1] >= min_order:
        return x  # you could also say `return (x[0], x[1])`
    else:
        return (x[0], x[1] + 10)

def l2(x):
    return (x[0], x[2] * x[3])

def l3(x):
    return l1(l2(x))
```

Thus, your final function is:

```
def l3(x):
    if x[2] * x[3] >= min_order:
        return (x[0], x[2] * x[3])
    else:
        return (x[0], x[2] * x[3] + 10)
```

This is basically what you have. To fix your code, you need to do a few things:

- This line:

  ```
  ordernum = L[item][0],
  ```

  Is equivalent to:

  ```
  ordernum = (L[item][0],)
  ```

  Which isn't really what you want ordernum to be. Get rid of the comma.
- You define `invoice_totals = []`, but you then overwrite it in the `if` statement. You need to append the total for each item to your list:

  ```
  def get_order(L):
      invoice_totals = []

      for item in range(len(L)):
          ordernum = L[item][0]

          if (L[item][2] * L[item][3])>= min_order:
              total = L[item][2] * L[item][3]
          else:
              total = L[item][2] * L[item][3] + 10

          invoice_totals.append((ordernum, total))

       return invoice_totals
  ```
- At this point you could also simplify the code:

  ```
  def compute_totals(orders):
      totals = []

      for order, description, quantity, price in orders:
          total = quantity * price

          if total < min_order:
              total += 10

          totals.append((order, total))

       return totals
  ```

Comment: Many thanks Blender!. I love the the variety solutions to one problem.